# Package vs Folder

Tags: apache-flex

Just for curiousity sake, what exactly is the difference between folders and packages?

Because I find I can use them pretty much interchangeably. Does anyone know what exactly the difference is? It seems the convention is to place classes inside packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just for curiousity sake, what exactly is the difference between
>   folders and packages?

There isn't one.  For all intents and purposes I would say that a package is a folder with a special purpose--to contain class files.

This isn't unique to Flex or ActionScript, most programming languages use the same approach and nomenclature.

Comment: There can be a difference in presentation though. Folders are always presented as a tree structure, whereas packages are commonly (not always) displayed as a list of dot-separated package names.

Comment: I don't disagree; but that is an IDE related thing and that doesn't change my answer.